# How to avoid seeing the contents of the previous modal before updating to the new one?

Tags: r, shiny

I am selecting a car from the table. A new popup window shows up. It displays the car one has selected. The first time it shows the car one has selected. From the second time the modal acts differently.

You can see after the second time that it first shows the previous one I selected and then updates it to the new one. How to turn this off?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)
library(tibble)

samplemodal <-  function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
        size = "l",
        easyClose = T,
        style = "width:100%",
        
        title = fluidRow("Species Selected", style = "color: #7B6B59;font-weight: bold", align =
                             "center"),
        
        fluidRow(column(3, strong("Car Selected")),
                 column(
                     9, div(style = "color: #009BD2;", textOutput("car_selected"))
                 )),
        
        footer = tagList(modalButton ("Cancel"))
    )
}

data <- mtcars %>% as_tibble(rownames = "cars")


ui <-
    fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, align = 'center', DTOutput("tbl"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues()
    
    output$tbl <-
        renderDataTable(data, selection = "single", rownames = FALSE)
    
    output$car_selected <- renderText({
        rv$selected_car
        
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$tbl_rows_selected, {
        selected_row_index <- input$tbl_rows_selected
        if (!is.null(selected_row_index)) {
            selected_car <- data$cars[selected_row_index]
            print(selected_car)
            rv$selected_car <- selected_car
            showModal(samplemodal())
        }
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: After `output$car_selected <- renderText({ rv$selected_car })`, add `outputOptions(output, "car_selected", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`.

Comment: yep thats what I thought.. it was working.. thanks anyways.. was about to mark it solved :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer is adding

```
outputOptions(output, "car_selected", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

The complete code is  :

```
library(shiny)
    library(shinyBS)
    library(DT)
    library(tibble)

samplemodal <-  function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
        size = "l",
        easyClose = T,
        style = "width:100%",
        
        title = fluidRow("Species Selected", style = "color: #7B6B59;font-weight: bold", align =
                             "center"),
        
        fluidRow(column(3, strong("Car Selected")),
                 column(
                     9, div(style = "color: #009BD2;", textOutput("car_selected"))
                 )),
        
        footer = tagList(modalButton ("Cancel"))
    )
}

data <- mtcars %>% as_tibble(rownames = "cars")


ui <-
    fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, align = 'center', DTOutput("tbl"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues()
    
    output$tbl <-
        renderDataTable(data, selection = "single", rownames = FALSE)
    
    output$car_selected <- renderText({
        rv$selected_car
        
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$tbl_rows_selected, {
        selected_row_index <- input$tbl_rows_selected
        if (!is.null(selected_row_index)) {
            selected_car <- data$cars[selected_row_index]
            print(selected_car)
            rv$selected_car <- selected_car
            showModal(samplemodal())
        }
    })

outputOptions(output, "car_selected", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```